# algorithm2e and \algomargin with negative value

Tags: margins, algorithms, lengths, algorithm2e

How can I use a negative length in `\algomargin` using algorithm2e? I get the unpleasant effect that the vertical lines and the caption are not moved accordingly, see for example:

[image: MWE image]

Note that this image is cut in the left incorrectly by the `standalone` document class (use `article` class instead).

The text "Algorithm 0.2" extends into the left margin (which is wanted) but the caption and the vertical lines are not. I am happy with any solution that lets me extend the algorithm environment slightly in the left and right margins, not necessarily using `\algomargin`.

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
%\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ruled,vlined,algosection]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm} normal computation \caption{normal algorithm} \end{algorithm}

\setlength{\algomargin}{-2em}
\begin{algorithm} long computation \caption{long algorithm} \end{algorithm}

\setlength{\algomargin}{2em}
\begin{algorithm} short computation \caption{short algorithm}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one possible solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,algosection]{algorithm2e}

\newlength\marincrease

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{Walgo}[2][htbp]
  {\renewcommand{\@algocf@start}{%
    \setlength\marincrease{#2}
  \@algoskip%
  \begin{lrbox}{\algocf@algobox}%
  \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth+2\marincrease\relax}
  \setlength{\algowidth}{\hsize}%
  \vbox\bgroup% save all the algo in a box
  \hbox to\algowidth\bgroup\hbox to \algomargin{\hfill}\vtop\bgroup%
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{algocf@slide}}{\parskip 0.5ex\color{black}}{}%
  % initialization
  \addtolength{\hsize}{-1.5\algomargin}%
  \let\@mathsemicolon=\;\def\;{\ifmmode\@mathsemicolon\else\@endalgoln\fi}%
  \raggedright\AlFnt{}%
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{algocf@slide}}{\IncMargin{\skipalgocfslide}}{}%
  \@algoinsideskip%
%   \let\@emathdisplay=\]\def\]{\algocf@endline\@emathdisplay\nl}%
  }%
\renewcommand{\@algocf@finish}{%
  \@algoinsideskip%
  \egroup%end of vtop which contain all the text
  \hfill\egroup%end of hbox wich contains [margin][vtop]
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{algocf@slide}}{\DecMargin{\skipalgocfslide}}{}%
  %
  \egroup%end of main vbox
  \end{minipage}
  \end{lrbox}%
  \makebox[\linewidth][c]{\algocf@makethealgo}% print the algo
  \@algoskip%
  % restore dimension and macros
  \setlength{\hsize}{\algowidth}%
  \lineskip\normallineskip\setlength{\skiptotal}{\@defaultskiptotal}%
  \let\;=\@mathsemicolon%  
  \let\]=\@emathdisplay%
}%
  \begin{algorithm}[#1]}
  {\end{algorithm}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Test Section}

\begin{Walgo}[ht]{20pt} 
\While{not at end of this document}
{
  read current\;
  \eIf{understand}
  {current section becomes this one\;}
  {go back to the beginning of current section and add osme more text to see the change in the margins\;}
}
\caption{How to write algorithms and some more text to see the effect of the change in the margins}
\end{Walgo}

\begin{algorithm}[ht] 
\While{not at end of this document}
{
  read current\;
  \eIf{understand}
  {current section becomes this one\;}
  {go back to the beginning of current section and add osme more text to see the change in the margins\;}
}
\caption{How to write algorithms and some more text to see the effect of the change in the margins}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{Walgo}[!ht]{2cm}
\While{not at end of this document}
{
  read current\;
  \eIf{understand}
  {current section becomes this one\;}
  {go back to the beginning of current section and add osme more text to see the change in the margins\;}
}
\caption{How to write algorithms and some more text to see the effect of the change in the margins}
\end{Walgo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `algorithm2e` package stores the algorithm inside the `lrbox` `\algocf@makethealgo` and then typesets it; I defined a new environment `Walgo` that uses a `minipage` inside this `lrbox`; the width of the `minipage` is `\textwidth+2\marginincrease`; then, the `\algocf@makethealgo` is placed inside a centered `\makebox` to typeset it.

The `Walgo` environment has one optional argument (the placement specifier) and a mandatory one (to give the `\marginincrease` lenght used to increase the margins).